# How can Magit add a credential to ssh-agent?

Tags: magit, ssh

Can I make Magit add my ssh passphrase to ssh-agent instead ask me to use the passphrase a single time?

Every time I push a commit to my remote I need to type my passphrase or instead run `M-& ssh-add PATH_TO_MY_CREDENTIAL` to add it to my ssh-agent.

Comment: What OS are you running? How are you starting `ssh-agent`?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu, I don't know exactly how `ssh-agent` was starting, but when I run `ssh-add CREDENTIAL` I don't need to type my password again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [ssh-agency](https://github.com/magit/ssh-agency) package for this.  It integrates with magit, and will run `ssh-add` as needed when you push.  If you don't have `ssh-askpass` installed, you will need a version which includes [this fix (pushed Apr 4, 2018)](https://github.com/magit/ssh-agency/pull/14) to successfully prompt for a passphrase on a Unixish system.

Note: I'm the author of this package.

Comment: I don't know if it requires a little of configuration, but it doesn't work for me... I installed using MELPA and add `(require 'ssh-agency)`. Then I did the test and the result was the same that I described in my question.

Comment: Ideally it shouldn't require any configuration. What's the result of `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, `echo $SSH_AUTH_PID`, and `ssh-add -l; echo $?` in a terminal; `(getenv "SSH_AUTH_SOCK")`, and `(ssh-agency-status)` in Emacs?

Comment: `echo $SSH_AUTH_PID` : `/tmp/ssh-OfgrvDM7CUHq/agent.1750` same result of `(getenv "SSH_AUTH_SOCK")`, now the `echo $SSH_AUTH_PID` returns nothing, `ssh-add -l;echo $?` returns "The agent has no identities." and "1", `(ssh-agency-status)` has returned `no-keys`. Before run this  comands I tried to push commits im my remote twice and all the time it requested me my passphrase.

Comment: Oh, I just realized I overlooked something, is `PATH_TO_MY_CREDENTIAL` some non-standard path (i.e., not one of `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, `~/.ssh/id_dsa`, `~/.ssh/id_ecdsa`, or `~/.ssh/id_ed25519`)? If so, you need to customize `ssh-agency-keys`.

Comment: But I think the content of `ssh-agency-keys` is right! When I get the variable content, it shows `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa_gateway`. And this is the current keys I have in  this host.

Comment: Hmm, if you evaluate `(ssh-agency-add-keys ssh-agency-keys)` do you get prompted for a passphrase?

Comment: No,  just  returned  `1`

Comment: Ah, `1` is the exit status of `ssh-add` meaning it failed for some reason. Try evaluating `(apply #'call-process ssh-agency-add-executable nil '(t t) t (mapcar #'expand-file-name ssh-agency-keys))` in `*scratch*` and see if it gives some useful error message.

Comment: It gives `(void-variable ssh-agency-add-executable)` (sorry for the troble man)

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem possible, do you not have `(defcustom ssh-agency-add-executable (ssh-agency-executable-find "ssh-add")...)` in `ssh-agency.el`?

Comment: hmmm my mistake man, I didn't `(require 'ssh-agency)` before run the last code you give to me. With the proper require, I got this message: `ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
`

Comment: Huh, that's a strange one (maybe [Debian Bug#325644](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=325644)?). Does `/usr/bin/ssh-askpass` exist? Do you have `SSH_ASKPASS` set (compare output of `echo $SSH_ASKPASS`  and `(getenv "SSH_ASKPASS")`)?

Comment: `/usr/bin/ssh-askpass` and `SSH-ASKPASS` doesn't exist in my machine. I'll read the bug to try to understand what is happening.

Comment: Ah, hold on, I can reproduce this on my Debian box, I must have missed it earlier because my key gets loaded outside of Emacs.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again @npostavs but did you find a fix?

Comment: @squiter, yup it should be fixed now (refer https://github.com/magit/ssh-agency/pull/14)

Comment: Wow, it works perfectly! Thank you so much!