# Use ssh-agent's SSH_AUTH_SOCK value, not macOS' one

Tags: magit, ssh, environment

When I run `(getenv "SSH_AUTH_SOCK")`, I get `"/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.K9OEFgxDgw/Listeners"`.

I want to set it to the value that is returned by `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` on the command line which is something like `/tmp/ssh-P7OPvY12nTFk/agent.35299`

Unfortunately, `(shell-command-to-string "echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK")` also returns `"/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.K9OEFgxDgw/Listeners"`.

How can I set `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` to `/tmp/ssh-XXXXXXXXX/agent.YYYYY`?

The background is that I want Magit to be aware of the SSH agent I'm running  so I can connect to Bitbucket repositories.

EDIT: I solved my problem by using the Keychain tool and keychain-environment for Emacs (see [this answer by the Magit author](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/41345/281)).

Comment: I assume this is the GUI vs command line environment thing of macOS? Perhaps https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell would help? (The name talks about exec-path, but afaik, it can be used for any environment variable)

Comment: How and where/when are you running the agent, and are you starting Emacs in that same environment?  If not, then obviously it can't inherit environment variables which aren't present at the time.

Comment: That said, do you actually need two?  Perhaps your real problem is that you're starting a second ssh-agent instead of using an existing one?

Comment: I run the agent manually from the command line. I start Emacs as a standard macOS application. Interestingly, when I start emacs with `--no-init`, `(shell-command-to-string "SSH_AUTH_SOCK") ` picks up the SSH agent socket under `/tmp`.

You're right at in the long term, I should figure out how to add Bitbucket to macOS system agent.